# Why some irrelevant words appearing in News Title?

Tags: google-search, search-results, google-news

When we search in Google with the published news title then some irrelevant words are showing in Google News section (See the attached image). These irrelevant words are coming only for the particular news portal. We have already check HTML data but nothing found there. Can anybody explain of the possible cause?

[image]

Comment: These are [labels](https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/4582731?hl=en): `Sometimes, label application is informed by publisher selection of appropriate tags in the Google News Publisher Center, or by the application of tags in HTML markup. We continually add new labels to help users understand and select the content they want to read. Labels not listed below are applied algorithmically.` If you use Google News Publisher Center, check if you're supplying labels. If not, then Google is choosing these algorithmically based on your content if they don't appear in your source.

Comment: "...irrelevant words appearing in News Title?" - This isn't the news "Title". Although, you appear to correct yourself in the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks, @dan Finally I have removed all of these levels from my news section.

Comment: @MazharulHaqSEO No problem. Feel free to add that as an answer and accept it when you can. That will complete the question and give you some extra reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are labels: Sometimes, label application is informed by publisher selection of appropriate tags in the Google News Publisher Center, or by the application of tags in HTML markup. We continually add new labels to help users understand and select the content they want to read. Labels not listed below are applied algorithmically. If you use Google News Publisher Center, check if you're supplying labels. If not, then Google is choosing these algorithmically based on your content if they don't appear in your source.

To complete the task please follow these steps:

You have to go to [Google News Publisher page.](https://news.google.com/publisher) Then click on **Details** option.

[image]

then click on **edit**

[image]

then click/select on **labels** option

[image]

If you want to show in Google News or if not to show in Google News then unselect which option you don't want.